# Clear previously selected table row, when the next row is selected

Tags: javascript, css

I have the following code to create a left and right border when a row is selected in a table. I want the borders to only appear when the row is currently selected, and to disappear when it is not selected.

I attach a mock up:

```js
function addRowHandlers() {
    var table = document.getElementById("example");
    var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
    for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var currentRow = table.rows[i];
        var createClickHandler =
            function(row) {
                return function() {
                    var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

                    row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
                    row.firstElementChild.style.borderLeft = "black solid 2px";
                    row.lastElementChild.style.borderRight = "black solid 2px";
                    var id = cell.innerHTML;
                    alert("id:" + id);
                };
            };

        currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
    }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

```css
tr td:first-child { border-left:2px solid transparent;}
tr td:last-child { border-right:2px solid transparent;}
```

```html
<div>
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>

</div>
```

Comment: First of all, you should rather set classes, instead of manipulating styles directly. And then of course you will have to _remove_ those styles from the previously “selected” row, when a new one is selected. Either loop over _all_ rows and remove them, before you set them for the current one; or store the reference to the previous row in a variable.

Comment: I gathered it is something like that, but I need some help doing that?

Comment: What with specifically? You are already looping over all rows once, so you already know how to do that.

Comment: As said by CBroe, you should consider adding a class 'active' on the selected cell. (suggesting cell.className = "active").

Then you can either "store" cell and delete this class when you enter the function. Or loop on your row and remove 'active' classes if exist.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use a class for the current selection styles ( I named it `highlight`) then on click remove this class from all rows with this

```
for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
     table.rows[i].classList.remove('highlight');
}
```

and then add it to the current row with `row.className += "highlight";` check it out:

```js
function addRowHandlers() {
  var table = document.getElementById("example");
  var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
  for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var currentRow = table.rows[i];
    var createClickHandler =
      function(row) {
        return function() {
          for (var i = 0; i < table.rows.length; i++) {
             table.rows[i].classList.remove('highlight');
          }
          
          var cell = row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0];

          row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor = "white";
          row.className += "highlight";
          var id = cell.innerHTML;
        };
      };

    currentRow.onclick = createClickHandler(currentRow);
  }
}
window.onload = addRowHandlers();
```

```css
tr:not(.highlight) td:first-child { border-left:2px solid transparent;}
tr:not(.highlight) td:last-child { border-right:2px solid transparent;}
tr.highlight td:first-child { border-left:2px solid black;}
tr.highlight td:last-child { border-right:2px solid black;}
```

```html
<div>
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <th>Firstname</th>
    <th>Lastname</th>
    <th>Age</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Jill</td>
    <td>Smith</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Eve</td>
    <td>Jackson</td>
    <td>94</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>80</td>
  </tr>
</table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you for explaining what you did. Appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here I tried a differenct approach with less code. 
If you inspect from console, you'll see the change: click event adds the class to that row, and resets other rows' classes.

```js
var mytable = document.getElementById("example");
var myrows = mytable.rows;

function giveStyle(el) {
  Array.from(myrows).map(e => e.className = "");
  el.className = "someclass";
}
```

```css
.someclass {
  /*something here */
}
```

```html
<table id="example">
  <tr>
    <td>First</td>
    <td>Last</td>
    <td>Age</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="giveStyle(this)">
    <td>John</td>
    <td>Doe</td>
    <td>50</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="giveStyle(this)">
    <td>Alice</td>
    <td>Wilsom</td>
    <td>40</td>
  </tr>
  <tr onclick="giveStyle(this)">
    <td>Otto</td>
    <td>Weininger</td>
    <td>25</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

Please use this function also :

```
function resetRowHandlers() {
        var table = document.getElementById("example");


        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr");
        for (i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
        var row = table.rows[i];

        row.getElementsByTagName("td")[0].style.backgroundColor = "none"; 
        row.firstElementChild.style.borderLeft = "transparent solid 2px";
        row.lastElementChild.style.borderRight = "transparent solid 2px";


        }
    }
```

Also call this function on click of row i.e. createClickHandler